# Trigger CSS animation fade-in & fade-out with JavaScript - only works in one direction?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to build a menu that fades in and out on click. This is the code:

HTML

```
<div id="trigger">CLICK</div>

<ul data-status="shown" id="navi">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes fade {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; display: block; }
}

ul {
  background: grey;
}

ul[data-status="shown"] {
   opacity: 1;
   animation: fade 2s;
}

ul[data-status="hidden"] {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fade 2s;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}

ul[data-status="removed"] {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function myMenu () {
    var trigger = document.getElementById( 'trigger' ),
        menu = document.getElementById( 'navi' ),
        state = menu.getAttribute( 'data-status' );

    if ( state == 'shown' ) {
        menu.removeAttribute( 'data-status' );
        menu.setAttribute( 'data-status', 'removed' );
        state = menu.getAttribute( 'data-status' );
    }

    var toggle = function () {
        if ( state == 'shown' ) {
            menu.removeAttribute( 'data-status' );
            menu.setAttribute( 'data-status', 'hidden' );
            setTimeout( function() {
                menu.removeAttribute( 'data-status' );
                menu.setAttribute( 'data-status', 'removed' );
                state = menu.getAttribute( 'data-status' );
            }, 2000 );
        }

        if ( state == 'removed' ) {
            menu.removeAttribute( 'data-status' );
            menu.setAttribute( 'data-status', 'shown' );
            state = menu.getAttribute( 'data-status' );
        }
    };

    trigger.addEventListener( 'click', toggle, false );

}

myMenu();
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/avUWUnO/1/edit

The fade-in works as expected, but the fade out is actually not present, the menu just disappears. Or maybe is this because I am clicking too fast? Then there is some strange delay in there, the error is probably where I use `setTimeout`, but I can't spot what's wrong there.

The status is set to hidden, the CSS animation fires, and two seconds later when the animation is finished, the menu is removed. Why is this not working as expected?

Comment: Jacedc is correct, but on a side note you should add some sort of timeout for the javascript or turn it into full CSS using a `label` and a hidden `input`

Comment: @Zeaklous Sorry I don't know hat you mean, what should be the value of that hidden field?

Comment: It's call [**the checkbox hack**](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/). I use it fairly often on pure CSS projects

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the vendor prefixes in the css properties. I changed any and all `animation` and `keyframe` selectors and added `-webkit-` (chrome and safari) and it worked.

Vendor prefixes are `-webkit-` (safari, and chrome < 27 I think), `-o-` is opera < 17, IE10 is the first browser to nix vendor prefixes so you don't have to worry about that, and `-moz-` is firefox. Be sure to include both the prefixed version and the non prefixed version.

So for instance, I only changed `-webkit-`:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; display: block; }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; display: block; }
}

ul {
  background: grey;
}

ul[data-status="shown"] {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-animation: fade 2s;
 animation: fade 2s;
}

ul[data-status="hidden"] {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fade 2s;
  -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
  animation: fade 2s;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

ul[data-status="removed"] {
  display: none;
}
```

But you may also want to add the rest of the prefixes.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/avUWUnO/7/edit) (thanks to Zeaklous for this.)

Comment: Of course you are right, these prefixes are missing, but I have tested it in Firefox 24 which doesn't need any prefixes and there only the fade-in is working correctly.

Comment: It does work in FF if you add back the original properties http://jsbin.com/avUWUnO/7/edit @Jacedc feel free to update your answer with it